# i am getting list out of index error while trying to run my lottery smart contract with brownie

Tags: contract-development, web3.py, python, brownie, solidity-0.6.x

PS E:\lottery-smartcontract> brownie run scripts/deploy_lottery.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

LotterySmartcontractProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic brownie --port 8545'...

Running 'scripts\deploy_lottery.py::main'...
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 49, in main
return_value, frame = run(
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
File ".\scripts\deploy_lottery.py", line 23, in main
deploy_lottery()
File ".\scripts\deploy_lottery.py", line 10, in deploy_lottery
get_contract("eth_usd_price_feed").address,
File ".\scripts\helpful_scripts.py", line 61, in get_contract
contract = contract_type[-1]
File "C:\Users\scs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 160, in **getitem**
return self._contracts[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
Terminating local RPC client...
[image]

Comment: You need to give more details like other parts of the code.

Comment: https://github.com/kamal2283/lottery_smart-contract

my code is uploaded here

Comment: does anybody has this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors:

Pubish_source should be publish_source

For your contract to mock dictionary in your helpful_scripts, vrf_cooridinator should be vrf_coordinator

For your get_contract function, deploy_mocks needs open and closing brackets after it as it is a function. [image]

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved now